# Gossip repository github: submodules not updating

Tags: ios, github, pjsip

I'm trying to program an SIPclient for iOS. After checking out different options, I decided to go with pjsip, and the gossip wrapper. Problem is, when i clone the gossip repository and try to update the submodules, the submodules doesn't update at all. Actually the folders are empty. I've asked a friend of mine which uses git alot, and I'm doing it correctly. (submodule init; submodule update). The submodule paths are present in the .gitmodules .

This is the repository:
https://github.com/chakrit/gossip

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some forgotten linking in the github repository it seems. I actually went with pjsip and cocoapods instead which, so far atleast, works like a charm.

Sidenote for Objective-C newbies like myself: You can actually use C-code as it is in Objective-C. If you've mainly been programming in java, take some time learning C, it helps alot if you need to use thirdparty stacks.